# iText7 Digital Signature Image Alignment

Tags: itext7

In iText7 when I add an image to a digital signature the image defaults to being right in the center of the Rect I've defined with any text aligned to the right. Is there a way to shift the image to aligned to the left of the digital signature's Rect?

com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image has a way to align itself to the left. But the PdfSignatureAppearance.setSignatureGraphic() requires an ImageData param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design the signature appearance in a completely custom manner by retrieving the `PdfFormXObject` *Layer 2* and drawing on it:

```
PdfSigner signer = ...
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
PdfFormXObject layer2 = appearance.getLayer2();
try (Canvas layer2Canvas = new Canvas(layer2, signer.getDocument())) {
    [... design your signature appearance on layer2Canvas ...]
}
```

If you don't want to do that, though, iText designs it itself hardly leaving you any options.

Comment: Making progress working with the PdfFormXObject. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.