# How to align content inside a signature box in iText 7

Tags: java, digital-signature, itext7

I have created a signature using iText 7 but I am not able to left - align the content of the signature (both image and text).
Decreasing the "width" component in Rectangle object, makes the signature have 3 lines instead of just two. Also the content shrinks up instead of sliding towards the left within the Rectangle.

[image] with Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 40, 170, 30) dimensions

**The content should be right at the starting of the box, in only 1 or 2 lines, as shown by the arrow below.**
[image]

with Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 40, 300, 30) dimensions

My Code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader r = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(src);

PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());

// Create the signature appearance
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 40, 300, 30);
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance

// Specify if the appearance before field is signed will be used
// as a background for the signed field. The "false" value is the default value.
.setReuseAppearance(false)
.setPageRect(rect)
.setPageNumber(r.getNumberOfPages());
signer.setFieldName("sig");

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
appearance.setLayer2Text("Digitally signed by XYZABC on " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));

// Set the rendering mode for this signature.
appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION);

ImageData image = ImageDataFactory.create(imagePath);

appearance.setSignatureGraphic(image);
appearance.setLayer2Font(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ITALIC));

// Creating the signature
IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

// Sign the document using the detached mode, CMS or CAdES equivalent.
// Pass the created TSAClient to the signing method.
signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
```

Any help with this is very much appreciated. Edits and further clarifications needed are welcomed.

Comment: If you want the layout to differ from what iText offers you, simply retrieve the `PdfFormXObject` returned by `appearance.getLayer2()` and draw on it exactly what you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635095/1729265).

Comment: See also the [Part IV - Appearances](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signing-with-itext-7/part-iv-appearances) of the iText knowledgebase article [Digital Signing with iText 7](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signing-with-itext-7). (The exact links may be subject to change over time.)

Answer (score 0):

You try the example.

```
appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
```

ro

```
appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
```

Comment: The OP currently also uses a signature graphic which would not should in case of `RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION`. If that graphic is not important or could also be applied as background graphic, though, using that rendering mode indeed would be an option.